# How to retrieve running version from ElasticBeanstalk app instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running a web server app in ElasticBeanstalk, using single Docker container config. I want to retrieve the current Running Version of the ElasticBeanstalk App somehow. I hoped there will be predefined environment variables from EB but there are none that could help.

Is there a programatic way to retrieve it from within the container?

Answer (score 0):

**EB CLI:** you can use EB CLI for this. "eb status" command will list out the status of your current EBS app.  You can filter your required parameters from the output.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cmd-commands.html

**AWS API:** You can also use "DescribeApplicationVersions" in AWS API to get the version.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_Operations.html

Basically you would need to upload the script or program in your docker container and run it for the container. Invoke the script in your dockerfile so that it does your job.